# Overload less than operator in c++ got an error

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

i  have a c++ program to overload less than operator and an error-
type name expected.
i want to overload < operator for just study of 12th class.

```
  bool operator <(abc x,abc y)
   {
     return(x.a<y.a);
   }
```

The full program:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
class abc
 {
  int a;
  public:
  abc()
  {
   a=0;
   }
  abc(int x)
  {
   a=x;
  }
  void show()
  {
   cout<<"\n"<<a;
  }

  bool operator <(abc x,abc y)
   {
     return(x.a<y.a);
   }


 };
void main()
 {
  clrscr();
  abc p(4),q(2);
  p.show();
  q.show();
  if(p<q)
   cout<<"\nP is Less than Q";
  getch();
 }
```

Comment: Can you show the error? And possibly provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Please make an effort to format your code properly - also please do not use `void main`.

Comment: `iostream.h`? Really? In the 16 years since the first C++ standard was released, this has never been correct.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you define `operator<` as a member function, it should only take one argument which is the second operand of the operator. The first operand is the object denoted by `*this`:

```
bool operator<(const abc& y)
{
  return(this->a < y.a);
}
```

Note that `main` should return an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

You defined the operator as a member function. In this case the left operand of the operator is `this`

The Correct definition will look as

```
bool operator <( const abc &rhs ) const
{
     return ( a < rhs.a );
}
```

Though it would be better if you would define it as a non-member function. For example

```
class abc
{
//...
   friend bool operator <( const abc &lhs, const abc &rhs );
//...
};

bool operator <<( const abc &lhs, const abc &rhs )
{
   return ( lhs.a < rhs.a );
}
```

Take into account that function main shall have return type `int`

Answer (score 0):

The operator< function should take only one argument. try this:

```
  bool operator <(abc& other)
   {
     return(a < other.a );
   }
```